# Unable to subscribe to platform event using emp api

Tags: apex, trigger, platform-event, cometd

I am trying to subscribe to my platform event using the empapi feature. This feature was added in v44.

I am following the example of the documentation page: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation

So far, I have created that lightning component and added it onto my visualforce page. When I click on the subscribe button, and send publish an event, nothing occurs and nothing happens in the console. Even the `empApi.subscribe` method doesn't seem to get called since the logs do not get produced. Any ideas?

Lightning Component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >

 <lightning:empApi aura:id="empApi" />

<lightning:input aura:id="channel" label="channel" name="channel" 
type="text" value="/event/EventP__e"/>
<lightning:button label="Subscribe" onclick="{!c.subscribe}" />
<lightning:button label="Unsubscribe" onclick="{!c.unsubscribe}" />
<aura:attribute name="sub" type="Object" />

<p>in the component</p>

</aura:component>
```

Lightning controller:

```
({
            // Client-side function that invokes the subscribe method on the
            // empApi component.
            subscribe : function(component, event, helper) {
                console.log('in the subscribe block');
                console.log('can use emp?:');
                // Get the empApi component.
                var empApi = component.find("empApi");

                console.log(empApi.isEmpEnabled);
                // Get the channel from the input box.
                var channel = component.find("channel").get("v.value");
                var replayId = -2;
                console.log(channel);
                console.log(replayId);
                console.log(empApi);
                // Callback function to be passed in the subscribe call.
                // After an event is received, this callback prints the event
                // payload to the console.
                var callback = function (message) {
                    console.log("Received [" + message.channel +
                        " : " + message.data.event.replayId + "] payload=" +
                        JSON.stringify(message.data.payload));
                }.bind(this);

                // Error handler function that prints the error to the console.
                var errorHandler = function (message) {
                    console.log("Received error ", message);
                }.bind(this);

                // Register error listener and pass in the error handler function.
                empApi.onError(errorHandler);

                var sub;
                // Subscribe to the channel and save the returned subscription object.
                empApi.subscribe(channel, replayId, callback).then(function(value) {
                    console.log("Subscribed to channel " + channel);
                    sub = value;
                    component.set("v.sub", sub);
                });
            },

            // Client-side function that invokes the unsubscribe method on the
            // empApi component.
            unsubscribe : function(component, event, helper) {
                // Get the empApi component.
                var empApi = component.find("empApi");
                // Get the channel from the input box.
                var channel = component.find("channel").get("v.value");

                // Callback function to be passed in the subscribe call.
                var callback = function (message) {
                     console.log("Unsubscribed from channel " + channel);
                }.bind(this);

                // Error handler function that prints the error to the console.
                var errorHandler = function (message) {
                    console.log("Received error ", message);
                }.bind(this);

               // Object that contains subscription attributes used to
               // unsubscribe.
                var sub = {"id": component.get("v.sub")["id"],
                           "channel": component.get("v.sub")["channel"]};

                // Register error listener and pass in the error handler function.
                empApi.onError(errorHandler);

                // Unsubscribe from the channel using the sub object.
                empApi.unsubscribe(sub, callback);
            }
        })
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page >
     <apex:includeLightning />

    <script>

        $Lightning.use("c:PlatformEventComp", function() {

        $Lightning.createComponent("c:EmpApiComp",

        "",

        "lightning",

        function(cmp) {

            // do some stuff
            console.log('here');

        });

    });

    </script>

    <div id="lightning" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you post the code? And is the lightning component works independently.

Comment: I edited the question to include code

Answer (score 4):

If you view the documentation for lightning:empApi, It only works in Lightning experience or Salesforce mobile.

[image]
I try to view your component as VF page or just the App then it fails to load.
then
I embedded your component into a flexiPage and see it works just fine.

[image]